# send very big data to an api in parallel and catching errors within promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-fetch

I have quite big data, to be sent to an api with node-fetch. But, since there are many data in the array, and I want to send the data in parallel, I wanted to use promise.allSettled...
Yet, it still takes too much time, and the execution get stuck.

my code is like this:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// ..... 
// get tokens for API and after receiving the token, call function to send the data

await sendToApi(token);

// .....

async function sendToApi(token) {

// headers and requestOptions are defined above (uses token)

 try {
    const responses = await Promise.allSettled(
      data.map(async (Item) => {
        path = 'my/path/';
        requestOptions.body = JSON.stringify(Item);
        const res = await fetch(path, requestOptions);
        console.log("res.status: ", res.status);
        return res;
      })
    );
    responses.forEach((response) => {
      console.log("response.status: ", response.status);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
  }
```

(if the data is small, i.e. when I truncate the data array, the above code and promise.allSettled works very well. But for real data size, it takes too long to process all the promises and also gets stuck (stops doing and after waiting quite a time i press cmd+C))

Therefore I thought, If I could divide the data in smaller portions and send async to a function, which contains promise.allSettled it could do well...

This is what I tried to do...

This is brute force, I mean, if it works, I will write a cleaner code to handle the logic...

```
// get tokens for API and after receiving the token, call function to send the data

await sendToApi(token);

// .....

async function sendToApi(token) {

// headers and requestOptions are defined above (uses token)
// data is the original big array (but for trial, even this is truncated)

await sendInGroups(data.slice(0, n), requestOptions);
await sendInGroups(data.slice(n + 1, 2 * n), requestOptions);
await sendInGroups(data.slice(2 * n + 1, 3 * n), requestOptions);

// .... it continues
```

and below, the function is just as above:

```
async sendInGroups(data), requestOptions) {
  try {
    console.log("in try");
    const responses = await Promise.allSettled(
      data.map(async (Item) => {
        path = 'my/path';
        requestOptions.body = JSON.stringify(Item);
        const res = await fetch(path, requestOptions);
        console.log("res.status: ", res.status);
        return res;
      })
    );
    responses.forEach((response) => {
      console.log("response.status: ", response.status);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
 }
}
```

all the promises return "rejected"...

ALSO, if I send ALL the DATA to this function (I mean, even if I don't slice them, the promises return rejected, again!)

try/catch doesnt give me the reason for errors. (I also tried several other options to catch the error and I could not achieve...)

my questions:

1. based on above structure how can i catch the error of rejected promise(s)?
2. why it does not work? Is my logic, dividing the data and sending in many functions async to work in parallel, false? Or is there some other thing I miss?

Thanks.

Comment: `Promise.allSettled()` usually doesn't throw, so your try-catch is redundant; you need to log the errors described by the objects (`{ status: "rejected", reason: "..." }`) of `responses`. Did you confuse `Promise.allSettled()` and `Promise.all()`?

Comment: you do know that the `async function sendToApi(token)` calls `sendInGroups` one after the other, not in parallel, right?

Comment: hi, I am not very good at async functions. But isn't it like, when we call a aswync function it is sent to event loop and returned after the operations is finished? Can I not call several async functions at the same time and see the result whichever returns first?

Comment: You can do that but that's not what you do. `await fn()` explicitly means that you need `fn()` to execute, then resolve, then return, *then* will the code continue onward.

Comment: Parallelizing isn't always better. In fact, it can make the total process slower. I'd recommend you first find out what your bottleneck is if you send everything serially. You're not going to get higher throughput if it's bandwidth for example.

Comment: @VLAZ, Jaromanda X thanks. I see your point. I have also written sample scripts, though I could not demonstrate the exact scenario.. anyway, HOW could I make the functions parallel? Can you recommend a solution or direct with a keyword? Meanwhile I am trying a hybrid solution. sending the data batches sequentially but the batches are sent with promise.allSettled... the batch sizes are way smaller...

Comment: @OskarGrosser, thanks... I preferred promise.allSettled bc in case of .all, if one promise is not fulfilled all others are rejected too... Do you mean the resolved promises inside, with `({ status: "rejected", reason: "..." })`... I will check.

Comment: @m-alptekin to make async calls *not* sequential, you need to call them without `await`. At which point, you need to collect the result and handle them. Which is where `Promise.all()` /  `Promise.allSettled()` comes in which you already use.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem.

Let me clarify it so that some day it may be useful for another one too...

I was trying to send a big chunk of data to an API. But first I did it sequentially, which took like forever...

Then, searching the web, I learned, sending in parallel could be done with promise.all or promise.allSettled...

So it is true... However, in my own case, I don't need the response from promise.all or promise.allSettled... Because I care about sending the data only...

waiting for the response of promise.all or promise.allSettled ALSO takes quite a time..

So the real solution is using "promise.any".. Which returns "fulfilled" even if one of the promises is approved...
There is no (or much less) time delay in this case...

here is a code snippet:

```
const responses = await Promise.any(
        vehData.map(async (vehItem) => {
          path = 'my/path/';
          // assign vehItem data to requestOptions...
          const res = await fetch(path, requestOptions);
          // console.log(res.status) // I only logged the outcome if it is NOT 201
```

Please check that I am not even using "responses" here.. I don't need it..

Thanks to all responders to my question.

Comment: If you don't need the responses, why are you waiting for anything at all?

Comment: What I did previously was sending an array of data sequentially with fetch... This took quite a time. After searching, sending data in parallel can be done with promise.all... That is why I wrote the above script... I could not find another way, to be honest...

Comment: No. Sending data in parallel is achieved by simply not waiting in the loop between firing off the requests, you don't need `Promise.all` or `Promise.any` for that. Those are only used if in the loop you collected the promises into an array, and then afterwards want to wait for all/any of them the fulfill. But if you don't want to wait, just don't wait!

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for your comment.. I am reading some docs on this and I think I get it finally (or soon will get it :))... Though the solution I provided gives what I wanted, I will check for other ways around too... One thing I observed, if I "fetch" without await, then the script is executed really fast but it seems that I cannot POST the data really... When I "await" I see that my data is sent... I am trying to understand the reason to this.